# Divisors asymptotics

Tags: number-theory

Let $\widetilde{\sigma_1(n)}$ denote the median of the sum of divisors of $n$, and let $\{d_1,d_2\}=$ pair of divisors of $n$ nearest to $\widetilde{\sigma_1(n)}$. Let $f(n)=d_1-d_2$ unless $n$ is a square, in which case $f(n)=0$. Then let $g(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\tfrac{f(k)}{k}$. $g(n)$ is then clearly equal to $O(\pi(n))$. A plot of $g(n)$ against $\pi(n)$ *(orange)* looks like this:

[image]

and $g(n)-\tfrac{7}{4}\pi(n)+2\log(n)+2\log\log(n)$ looks like this:

[image]

Are there any better asymptotics than this?